# How do that Pager re-created the page

Tags: android

I use Pager in my application. The Pager remembers one page left and right. I want that Pager didn't remember page. I want that it is always re-created the page. How I can do it?
my Pager

```
    private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.d(Tag, "getItem");
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        MySqlCursorAdapter.prevDate = null;
        Log.d(Tag, "getCount.. получаем количество страниц"+PAGE_COUNT);
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.d(Tag, "getPageTitle");
        return "Title " + position;
    }


    // Код из FragmentPagerAdapter.java

    private String makeFragmentName(int viewId, long id) {
        Log.d(Tag, "makeFragmentName");
        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
    }

}
```

help me please.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not easy because of pager itself support swiping gesture, it means if a user swipe a screen, it should display left or right page, and therefore three page are all prepared at the same time.

So, if you really want to always re-create the page eachtime, you may consider using [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) or [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) as alternative.

Another option is updating page whenever a user swipe a page totally. You can check this timing via setting a [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) at your ViewPager.

```
        mMyPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                //do some update job here.
            }

           @Override
           public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
                if(isVisibleToUser){
                    //reset the values of your fragment 
                }

    }
```